# Accepting answer is impossible using Safari on iOS 6

Tags: bug, ipad, safari

Yesterday I posted about the fact that I can't accept answers even though the last edit for answer was long ago. After cookie deletion, I managed to accept one.

When I click on tick to accept answer, I get message box saying that I can't accept answer in X minutes. After this X minutes the message box appears and text is the same. I am using regular view I believe.

Today the story repeated. Refreshing the page didn't help. After logging out and logging in again I **could** accept the answer.

I believe that this is bug. Please take a look at it.

I am accessing Stack Overflow from an iPad 2 with iOS 6, Safari browser.

Comment: Can you try this again? We are explicitly telling iOS 6 not to cache POSTs until Apple releases a fix since it's affecting so many people.

Comment: Now the answer was accepted, but I can't revert accepting, I mean when I again click on a tick - nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug on the Apple side in Mobile Safari in iOS6, you can read about it here:

[Is Safari on iOS 6 caching $.ajax results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506897/is-safari-on-ios-6-caching-ajax-results)

Hopefully Apple releases an iOS update with a fix for this ASAP, it's affecting many many website AJAX interactions.

Comment: either that, or we will see a big increment on people using Chrome or FireFox